# adding rating star javascript error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement rating system.

What I tried:

> When user clicks any of the stars, I try to add a class to stars before it and clicked star.

But it adds class to all the stars in the `td`

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Rating </th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr>
            <td class="hd">usertext1</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="hd">usertext</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="hd">feedback text</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>

            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-star rating" aria-hidden="true"></i>

            </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


    <style>
    .ratingstar{
      color:#FFD700
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.rating').on('click', function(){
       var sel = $(this);
       var td = sel.parents('td').find('.rating');
       td.each(function(item){
           if($(this)==sel){
             console.log(item);//I tried break here but It throws error

           }
           $(this).addClass('ratingstar');
       })
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually really easy with chaining:

```
$('.rating').on('click', function(){
    $(this)                     // Our starting point, we're going left/right of this one
        .addClass('starred')    // Of course, activate the one selected
        .nextAll()              // Select the "unstarred"
        .removeClass('starred') // Deactivate greater ratings not selected
        .end()                  // This cancels the .nextAll() sub-selector, back to this
        .prevAll()              // Get the lower stars
        .addClass('starred')    // Activate them
    ;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9364fusb/2

Answer (score 1):

This will work for modern browsers:

```
$('.rating').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('ratingstar');

    var prev = this.previousElementSibling;

    while (prev) {
        $(prev).addClass('ratingstar');
        prev = prev.previousElementSibling;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain your actual problem, jQuery returns an array-like object. `$(this) == sel` will always evaluate false in the same way `[] == []` is false because each array has a unique reference.  To test for equivalence the API includes the [`$.is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function. e.g. (sticking with your original code):

```js
$('.rating').on('click', function() {
    var sel = $(this);
    var td = sel.parents('td').find('.rating');
    td.removeClass('ratingstar').each(function(item) {
        $(this).addClass('ratingstar');
        if ($(this).is(sel))
            return false;
    });
});
```

[**» Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/21vwL5yc/)